# Which ejabberd module handles directed presence events?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am modifying the ejabberd server to send a custom roster to the user which I was able to do by writing my own version of mod_roster. Now I want to add presence on top of that roster by handling directed presence messages from the client as defined in [rfc3921](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#presence).

Does anyone know which modules currently provide this functionality so I can use them as a reference?

Comment: I think I'm building something like what *you* were building back in May :D I have a custom mod_roster that sends custom rosters to users, but those users don't get presence notifications when someone goes online... May I ask why you went for directed presence messages? Is there no way to set up ejabberd to send those presence messages according to the rosters? (Assuming that I understood correctly and "directed presence messages" means that the client itself sends those messages, instead of the server)

Comment: (For the record, right now I'm trying to customise get_subscriptions_list)

Comment: I have been off this project for a while but as far as I recall, When a client connects it sends a broadcast presence message to all friends as far as I remember. However, it does not know which friends are online. To handle that case we send a directed presence request.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail I am trying to do something close to what you did.Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972278/extending-ejabberd-with-modules-for-custom-mysql-schema

Comment: I never got far enough along on this project before it was canned to give you a definite answer. However, I have forwarded the question to few people who know more about this than I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific module for this but ejabberd_cs2.erl has most of the code which handles this functionality.